# Which event applies UICulture to Page

Tags: asp.net, localization

I know how to apply Localization to a page by creating the resource file. but one thing is really hurting to my mind since few days is, How the UIculture is getting applied to a ASP.NET page in the background of the screen ?

The thoughts coming to mind is in the events of Page Life Cycle. 
If yes, then in which event and how to test that?

Please clarify.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the culture and UI culture for an ASP.NET Web page declaratively

To set the UI culture and culture for all pages, add a globalization section to the Web.config file, and then set the uiculture and culture attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
<globalization uiculture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

To set the UI culture and culture for an individual page, set the Culture and UICulture attributes of the `@ Page` directive, as shown in the following example:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

To have ASP.NET set the UI culture and culture to the first language that is specified in the current browser settings, set UICulture and Culture to `auto`. Alternatively, you can set this value to `auto:culture_info_name`, where `culture_info_name` is a culture name. For a list of culture names, see CultureInfo. You can make this setting either in the `@ Page` directive or Web.config file.

To set the culture and UI culture for an ASP.NET Web page programmatically

1. Override the InitializeCulture method for the page.
2. In the overridden method, determine which language and culture to set the page to.

   - Note: The InitializeCulture method is called very early in the page life cycle, before controls are created or properties are set for the page. Therefore, to read values that are passed to the page from controls, you must get them directly from the request using the Form collection.
3. Set the UI culture and culture in one of the following ways:

   - Set the Culture and UICulture properties of the page to the language and culture string (for example, `en-US`). These properties are internal to the page, and can only be used in a page.
   - Set the CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture properties of the current thread to the UI culture and culture, respectively. The CurrentUICulture property takes a language and culture information string. To set the CurrentCulture property, you create an instance of the CultureInfo class and call its CreateSpecificCulture method.

C# code sample:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["ListBox1"];
        UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
        Culture = selectedLanguage ;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

See below for a detailed page lifecycle:

1. Construct
2. ProcessRequest
3. FrameworkInitialize
4. **InitializeCulture**
5. If child controls are present

   1. AddParsedSubObject
   2. CreateControlCollection
   3. AddedControl
   4. ResolveAdapter
6. DeterminePostBackMode
7. OnPreInit
8. OnInit
9. TrackViewState
10. OnInitComplete
11. OnPreLoad
12. OnLoad
13. OnLoadComplete
14. EnsureChildControls

    1. CreateChildControls
15. OnPreRender
16. OnPreRenderComplete
17. SaveViewState
18. OnSaveStateComplete
19. CreateHtmlTextWriter
20. RenderControl
21. Render

    1. RenderChildren
    2. VerifyRenderingInServerForm
22. OnUnload
23. Dispose

Comment: Here are other, more detailed page lifecycle details, yet it does not mention `InitializeCulture`: [ASP.NET 2.0 page life cycle poster by Léon Andrianarivony](http://emanish.googlepages.com/Asp.Net2.0Lifecycle.PNG)

Answer (score 2):

Besides settings in `web.config`, and page tag there is a page method `InitializeCulture()`, you can override it to include you extra logic.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
   // include your extra logic
   //base.Culture
   base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Comment: When this method gets called in the Page Life Cycle ?